# Google Analytics not counting all real time visitors

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, google-analytics

I used to buy popup traffic for my website. I noticed that only 500-600 out of 1000 popup visitors are tracked by google analytics. I did used link shortner to check whether 1000 were delivered or not. Don't know what's causing the problem. My website doesn't slows down with 1000-2000 visitors.

What I think is, since its popup traffic most of the users close their tab before GA script is loaded.
My VPS specs:

> RAM: 12 GB
>   SSD:300 GB 
>   CPU: 4 Core Intel E5

I am using wordpress running on apache, php7 fcgi. 
Is there anyway to make GA script load first than any other element on a page so that all 1000 popup visitors are counted?

Comment: What kind of human can open a tab and close it in mere milliseconds? It must be something else...

Comment: So, I think GA script must be taking some time to load.

Comment: The `GA` script is probably placed too low down the DOM tree and waits for other resources to load first. You could try placing it before other `stylesheets` and `scripts` provided that you have control over the `HTML` structure of the page.

Comment: So they leave your page before it is even completly loaded? they must see something they don't like then :-D

Comment: Most traffic you can buy for cheap is delivered by bots. Compare your logs, and see how many of your "visitors" actually load CSS/JS/images.